# How to put background image behind a set of radio buttons

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to put a background image in a div that has some radio buttons, and have it update with angular depending on which page we are sitting on.

```js
app.controller('thingCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams) {
    console.log("Inside thingCtrl");
    $scope.title = "Thing";
    $scope.talkingPointsImage = "img/thing.svg";
}
```

```css
main:after {
  opacity: 0.25;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="main" style="background: url({{talkingPointsImage}});">
<div class="talking-points">
  
 <h2>{{title}}</h2>
 <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="issue in subCategories">
         <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="question.stance" ng-value="-1"> {{issue.issue}}
     </li>
 </ul>
 

</div>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

I'm having trouble getting it to show up the way I need. The routing with {{}} is definitely working, but I can't get it to be sized correctly.

The image is showing up but has no transparency, and is not sized correctly.

1) it should have transparency to make it appear faint, and be in the background and not obscure the information in front of it, which should still be clickable.

2) it should be sized to sit comfortably behind the information which is maybe 200px by 200px

Comment: Please be more specific. The background image is not showing up?

Comment: Can you define "sized correctly"? And what's `main:after` got to do with it?

Comment: If you need to stretch the background image, I suggest to use `cover` or `contain`: `<div class="main" style="background: url({{talkingPointsImage}}) cover;">`. Google for "css background cover contain".

Comment: `main:after` => `.main:after`

Comment: no .main:after isn't the problem saw it and fixed it

Comment: the image is showing up but has no transparency - it should have transparency to make it appear faint, and be in the background and not obscure the information in front of it, which should still be clickable. That is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best answer because there is one limitation.
You must set fixed size for the `height` and `width` of the background image if you want to do it only with CSS.
We can fix that but it requires little bit of jQuery. I'm not fan of this type of way but im going to post it just in case you want to try it out.
If you want to set the `width` and `height` of the image to be the same as the content div just uncomment the jQuery code.

```js
/*$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#first").css("height", $("#second").height());
    $("#first").css("width", $("#second").width());
});*/
```

```css
#main {
    position:relative;
}
div#first {
    background-size: cover; /* if you want to stretch the background */
    opacity:0.2;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
}
div#second {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <div id="first" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x500');"></div>
    <div id="second">
        <div class="talking-points">
            <h2>{{title}}</h2>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="issue in subCategories">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="question.stance" ng-value="-1">{{issue.issue}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```